# Can I down-cast a class forcing it to lose the original constructor/s?

Tags: flutter, dart, type-inference, downcast, inference

---

- run the code below on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```dart
class Foo {
  const Foo(this.message);
  final String message;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  const Bar(String message, this.another,) : super(message); 
  final String another;
}

void main() {
  const Foo _foo = Bar('hello','world');
  const Bar _bar = _foo;
  print(_bar.another);
}
```

---

- at the moment of writing, with darpad `Based on Flutter 1.22.0-12.1.pre Dart SDK 2.9.3`

  the output is `world`

---

this is the typical behavior that we experience with every `Widget`,

but is there a way to force the Object to lose the "extra" constructor

***without recasting the whole Object***?

Comment: oh... that's awesome! if you care about stack reputation make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nobody calls it, it will go away due to treeshaking.